# How to remove a percentage from a dataset in Weka but keep the class balance?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, training-data, statistical-sampling

I have a data set with 50% instances from class A and 50% instances of class B. I want to split my data set into a training set and a test set. I know the RemovePercentage filter exists but it doesn't care about the class balance. How do I remove 35% from my data set but still keep a 50/50 class distribution in the training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way using the filter StratifiedRemoveFolds:

**Step 1**

Open your data set in the Weka Explorer and choose the supervised instance filter StratifiedRemoveFolds.

**Step 2**

Decide the sizes you want for your training and test set. If you want your sets to have an equal size then pick for **numFolds** 2. Apply the filter. This will generate a data set that contains 50 % of the data from the original set. (If you want 67 % train data and 33 % test data then pick 3 for numFolds)

**Step 3**

Save this generated set as f.e. "train.arff". When the first set is saved you must Undo the action so that you are back with your full data set.

**Step 4**

Click on the StratifiedRemoveFolds filter and change the parameter **invertSelection** from False to True. Now when you apply that filter a set will be generated like in step 2 but it will contain the other 50 % of the data set.

**Step 5**

Save this as "test.arff**. Now you have a train and test set that respect your class balance.

Comment: One thing to note that if **numFolds** is set to n (where n != 2), the first filtered data set contains 1/n of the original, which shall be named "test.arff".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Stratified Remove Folds.  It strives to maintain the original class distributions.  http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/supervised/instance/StratifiedRemoveFolds.html

Comment: It works to generate a test set using Stratified Remove Folds but those instances aren't removed from the whole data set so my training set still has the instances from the test set.